# How can I automatically change to a different WiFi with better link speed?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have two access points (with different SSIDs), and sometimes one gets better link speed than the other. I want to periodically (for example, every 10 minutes) check which one has the higher link speed, in a none-marginal difference, and connect to that access point.

How can I do that with a script or any other utility?

Comment: Take a look [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/bbzm9t/automatically_switch_to_the_strongest_wifi_signal/).

Comment: Thanks Mitch! Exactly what I needed.